# What Firefox is using as a js engin SpiderMonkey or IonMonkey

Tags: firefox, spidermonkey, javascript-engine, ionmonkey

I got confused when I read [this Wikipedia page about SpiderMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey)

What Firefox is currently using for js SpiderMonkey, IonMonkey, JägerMonkey or a combination of them?

Thank you

Comment: From the wiki "SpiderMonkey is written in C/C++ and contains an interpreter, the IonMonkey JIT compiler, and a garbage collector."

Comment: Thanks @scrappedcola , but what about JagarMonkey. Is it currently used?

Comment: "It was first released in Firefox 4 and eventually entirely supplanted TraceMonkey. It has itself been replaced by IonMonkey". Replaced by Trace which was replaced by Ion

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort :)

Comment: For last years FF using only SpiderMonkey